# Can anyone help how i can write this line of code.I want use map in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to use map in my Jsx in react and it has error because I use it with ternary expressions. Can anyone help me?

```
{tf > 0 ? {products.map(product => <CartProduct key={product.id} productData={product}/>)} : ''}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please add that.

Comment: You need to add more information, like what affects the variable `tf`.. and include the error as well

Comment: @Sepehr - Why have you still not updated the question with the error and more context? Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{tf > 0 ? products.map(product => <CartProduct key={product.id} productData={product}/>) : null}
```

You need to remove block scope (`{}`) around the `products.map` call, and don't return empty string `''` in JSX; instead return `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You have error in your syntax. You should not use curly braces if you are returning directly. Curly `{}` braces are only used when you have some processing/calculations to do and then don't want to return anything or if return something and not the complete function which you wrote. For example, use curly braces here:

```
const temp = () => {
  let a=20;
  console.log('a',a);
};
```

Notice that I don't want to return anything in the function.

However, if you don't have anything to process or want to directly return what you are processing, use round `()` brackets.

```
const temp = () => {
  let a = 20;
  console.log('a', a);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hi</h1> there
    </div>
  );
};
```

Notice that I am returning multiple lines above.

Also, if you have multiple lines of code to return, then use round `()` brackets, otherwise just return the value.

```
const temp = () => {
  let a = 20;
  console.log('a', a);

  return 'Hi';
};
```

In this ternary operator, you are returning `products.map(...` function and for each product, you are returning `<CartProduct` component. This is a single statement (since map is a function), so you don't need to use round `()` also. So, the correct way to write the code is:

```
{tf > 0 ? products.map((product) => <CartProduct key={product.id} productData={product} />) : ''}
```

However, if you want to use round `()` brackets for single-lined return statements, you can do that too.

```
const temp = () => {
    let a = 20;
    console.log('a', a);
    return ('Hi');
};
```

So, you can also rewrite your code as:

```
{tf > 0 ? (products.map((product) => <CartProduct key={product.id} productData={product} />)) : ''}
```

Both the ways are correct.